# iPhone image (binary) file post to a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, file-upload, authenticity-token

I am a backend Rails developer of an API.  The API must accept an image upload from an iPhone client.

My question is what the Content-Type for the entire POST must be to allow the upload and not get trapped by the InvalidAuthenticityToken issue.  It will have to be a multipart type because there are (in one case) 3 image files, and the normal textual POST parameters.  We have control of the iPhone code, and would rather not make it e.g., a two stage where a token is requested from the server and then is submitted with the POST.

Thanks,
Craig Cook

Answer (score 1):

You'll just want to tell the controller to bypass the authenticity token for your API based POST.

```
class Api::PhotoController < Api::ApiController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    ...
  end
end
```

That way